# How to find all paths from node and filter by relationship property?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a graph like this:
[image: my graph]

I want to find all path from given node with relationship property(each node has param `id`). Relationship `RELATED_TO` has property `type`.

The logic from 10 to 1(through 3): 10 ->(type: type1) 5 ->(type: type1) 3 ->(type: type1) 1

The logic from 10 to 1(through 2): 10 ->(type: type1) 5 ->(type: type1) 2 ->(type: type2) 1;

Example:

- node.id: `10`
- rel.type: `type1`

Expected output: 10 -> 5 -> 3 -> 1 and 10 -> 5 -> 2

How to write the cypher?

Comment: what is the logic (rule) to from 10 to 1 and 10 to 2? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing by `rel.type` you mean there is a `type` property on your `RELATED_TO` relationships and you want to ensure the value is `type1` and also assuming that when you mean `node:10` it means the node with id `10`, you can do it with the following query :

```
MATCH path=(n)-[r:RELATED_TO* {type: 'type1'}]->(o)
WHERE id(n) = 10
RETURN path
```

Comment: Using this query I always get the original graph

Comment: Are you sure, if you tried in the Neo4j browser make sure the option "connect result nodes" is disabled, otherwise it will automatically pull the links existing between visualised nodes from the db.
Switch to table result view and you will see the original graph doesn't appear.

Comment: Problem was in "connect result nodes" option. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use APOC plugin:

```
MATCH (n:Node{key: 10})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(n, {
    relationshipFilter: "RELATED_TO>"
})
YIELD path
RETURN nodes(path)
```